# Oracle SQL - Can anyone make this more effiecient?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization

A bit of flavour to go with this - This is a query that is called from a crystal report which searches using a carton number that was split into two cartons and returns both carton numbers, their quantity, the amount removed from the original, the user and the trailer number if it was loaded onto one already.

The first part of the query works great, unfortunately all data is archived after 30 days and the archive is massive! Once the archive section is added this query can take anywhere between 30 and 45 minutes to run which is far too long. Can anyone help me optimize this query so it can run faster?

Many thanks, 7's.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT menu_optn_name,
          tran_nbr,
          seq_nbr,
          cntr_nbr,
          ch.total_qty ,
          ptt.create_date_time,
          um.user_name,
          ch.trlr_nbr,

     (SELECT sum(ref_field_2)
      FROM prod_trkg_tran
      WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
        AND cntr_nbr = '0030651942') AS Total
   FROM prod_trkg_tran ptt
   INNER JOIN user_master um ON um.emplye_id = ptt.user_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
   WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
     AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942'
   GROUP BY menu_optn_name,
            tran_nbr,
            seq_nbr,
            cntr_nbr,
            ch.total_qty,
            ptt.create_date_time,
            um.user_name,
            ch.trlr_nbr
   UNION SELECT menu_optn_name,
                tran_nbr,
                seq_nbr,
                cntr_nbr,
                ch.total_qty,
                ptt.create_date_time,
                um.user_name,
                ch.trlr_nbr,

     (SELECT sum(ref_field_2)
      FROM prod_trkg_tran
      WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
        AND cntr_nbr NOT IN
          (SELECT cntr_nbr
           FROM prod_trkg_tran ptt
           LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
           WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
             AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')
        AND tran_nbr IN
          (SELECT tran_nbr
           FROM prod_trkg_tran ptt
           LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
           WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
             AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')) AS Total
   FROM prod_trkg_tran ptt
   INNER JOIN user_master um ON um.emplye_id = ptt.user_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
   WHERE cntr_nbr NOT IN
       (SELECT cntr_nbr
        FROM prod_trkg_tran ptt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
        WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
          AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')
     AND tran_nbr IN
       (SELECT tran_nbr
        FROM prod_trkg_tran ptt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
        WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
          AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')
   GROUP BY menu_optn_name,
            tran_nbr,
            seq_nbr,
            cntr_nbr,
            ch.total_qty,
            ptt.create_date_time,
            um.user_name,
            ch.trlr_nbr)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT menu_optn_name,
          tran_nbr,
          seq_nbr,
          cntr_nbr,
          ch.total_qty,
          ptt.create_date_time,
          um.user_name,
          ch.trlr_nbr,

     (SELECT sum(ref_field_2)
      FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com
      WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
        AND cntr_nbr = '0030651942') AS Total
   FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
   INNER JOIN user_master um ON um.emplye_id = ptt.user_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN carton_hdr ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
   WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
     AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942'
   GROUP BY menu_optn_name,
            tran_nbr,
            seq_nbr,
            cntr_nbr,
            ch.total_qty,
            ptt.create_date_time,
            um.user_name,
            ch.trlr_nbr
   UNION SELECT menu_optn_name,
                tran_nbr,
                seq_nbr,
                cntr_nbr,
                ch.total_qty,
                ptt.create_date_time,
                um.user_name,
                ch.trlr_nbr,

     (SELECT sum(ref_field_2)
      FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com
      WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
        AND cntr_nbr NOT IN
          (SELECT cntr_nbr
           FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
           LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_archive.carton_hdr@awm.corp.*******.com ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
           WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
             AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')
        AND tran_nbr IN
          (SELECT tran_nbr
           FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
           LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_archive.carton_hdr@awm.corp.*******.com ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
           WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
             AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')) AS Total
   FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
   INNER JOIN user_master um ON um.emplye_id = ptt.user_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_archive.carton_hdr@awm.corp.*******.com ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
   WHERE cntr_nbr NOT IN
       (SELECT cntr_nbr
        FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_archive.carton_hdr@awm.corp.*******.com ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
        WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
          AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')
     AND tran_nbr IN
       (SELECT tran_nbr
        FROM wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_archive.carton_hdr@awm.corp.*******.com ch ON ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
        WHERE menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}'
          AND ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942')
   GROUP BY menu_optn_name,
            tran_nbr,
            seq_nbr,
            cntr_nbr,
            ch.total_qty,
            ptt.create_date_time,
            um.user_name,
            ch.trlr_nbr)
WHERE rownum <=2;
```

Comment: Why are you using SELECT SUM(ref_field_2) FROM... all over the place? It would seem you are executing a subselect to sum the same exact rows that are being aggregated in the parent select.

Comment: The first use is used during the first carton number selection, the second use is to find the carton number that is not the first number. It is used exactly twice in each query.

Comment: That is not what I am saying... each single subSELECT SUM FROM... is using the same rows that are being aggregated in the corresponding parent select... why?

Comment: I'm not sure i see what you mean. The SELECT SUM(ref_field_2) is summing all rows in the query result because there will be more than 2 rows returned, i'm only interested in the first 2 for all the data apart from ref_field_2 which must all be combined.

Comment: Could you please tell me which columns reside on which table? I'm interested in menu_opt_name, cntr_nbr and tran_nbr. Another thing... how many rows does the condition menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942' isolate?

Comment: menu_opt_name, cntr_nbr and tran_nbr are all on prod_trkg_tran table. 
If i run the section you requested seperately it only returns one row. Carton 0030651942 has tran number 187759563 - This tran number is the column holding everything together. If i run a select by tran number = 187759563 then i can return something like this:-

MENU_OPTN_NAME    TRAN_NBR SEQ_NBR CNTR_NBR
 
RF Split/Comb {Carton} **187759563  1 0030651942**

RF Split/Comb {Carton} **187759563  2 0030680245**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51249/discussion-between-frazz-and-luckysevens)

Comment: Hi, please don't dump a huge amount of code and hope that someone will help. It would be standard practice to post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that completely demonstrates your problem. It seems, though, that your question can be boiled down into 1 statement, you're trying to get a lot of data cross-database and it's slow. So, what are the indexes on the tables you're retrieving data from? What is the amount of data you're retrieving and how quick is the network you're pulling the data through?

Comment: @Ben To be honest i didn't really want to post a massive block of code but it would be probably just as un-helpful to post a question saying what i'm doing and that it is very slow. As for indexes, data amount and network speed i have no idea. I can say i'm using the network of the largest company of it's kind in the UK so i would say that isn't an issue and realistically the data amount is quite minimal. _I was thinking that someone might simply point out a simple way to cut down the complexity of my code_. Frazz has done that and even though it doesn't work that was all i could ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible optimizations for this query.

The first is that:

```
SELECT key, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table WHERE condition) AS Total
FROM table WHERE condition
GROUP BY key
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
SELECT key, SUM(value)
FROM table WHERE condition
GROUP BY key
```

... but potentially much less efficient.

The second is that:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE condition_1 GROUP BY x,y
UNION
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE condition_2 GROUP BY x,y
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE condition_1 OR condition_2 GROUP BY x,y
```

That is, if condition_1 and condition_2 only reference columns which appear in the GROUP BY clause, like your case. There may be some differences in order, but they can be solved with explicit ORDER BY clause, if necessary.

That said, it would seem possibile to eliminate 4 subselects and 2 unions. Taking into account that all columns for the WHERE filters reside in prod_trkg_tran table, you can also remove some LEFT JOINs. So it would look something like this:

```
   select * from (
         select menu_optn_name, tran_nbr, seq_nbr, cntr_nbr, ch.total_qty, ptt.create_date_time, um.user_name, ch.trlr_nbr, sum(ref_field_2) as Total
         from            prod_trkg_tran ptt
         inner join      user_master    um  on um.emplye_id = ptt.user_id
         left outer join carton_hdr     ch  on ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
         where (menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942') or (
            cntr_nbr not in (
               select cntr_nbr
               from prod_trkg_tran
               where menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and cntr_nbr = '0030651942'
            ) and
            tran_nbr in (
               select tran_nbr
               from prod_trkg_tran 
               where menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and cntr_nbr = '0030651942'
            )
         )
         group by menu_optn_name, tran_nbr, seq_nbr, cntr_nbr, ch.total_qty, ptt.create_date_time, um.user_name, ch.trlr_nbr
   )
union
   select * from (
         select menu_optn_name, tran_nbr, seq_nbr, cntr_nbr, ch.total_qty, ptt.create_date_time, um.user_name, ch.trlr_nbr, sum(ref_field_2) as Total
         from            wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
         inner join      user_master                                    um  on um.emplye_id = ptt.user_id
         left outer join carton_hdr                                     ch  on ch.carton_nbr = ptt.cntr_nbr
         where (menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and ptt.cntr_nbr = '0030651942') or (
            cntr_nbr not in (
               select cntr_nbr
               from wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com
               where menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and cntr_nbr = '0030651942'
            ) and
            tran_nbr in (
               select tran_nbr
               from wm_archive.prod_trkg_tran@awm.corp.*******.com ptt
               where menu_optn_name = 'RF Split/Comb {Carton}' and cntr_nbr = '0030651942'
            )
         )
         group by menu_optn_name, tran_nbr, seq_nbr, cntr_nbr, ch.total_qty, ptt.create_date_time, um.user_name, ch.trlr_nbr
   )
where rownum <=2;
```

There also is a third optimization. The INNER JOIN on user_master can be moved out from the internal selects to the outer union. But I doubt that this join is costing much.